# One of two Custom Post types not being registered

Tags: custom-post-types

I have this function that adds to custom post types which is very simple and straight forward as seen below;

```
function create_hr_post_type() {

  register_post_type( 'informationtechnology',
    array(
      'labels' => array(
        'name' => __( 'Information Technology' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'Information Technology' )
      ),
      'public' => true,
      'has_archive' => true,
      'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'informationtechnology'),
    )
  );

  register_post_type( 'humanresource',
    array(
      'labels' => array(
        'name' => __( 'HR' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'HR' )
      ),
      'public' => true,
      'has_archive' => true,
      'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'humanresource'),
    )
  );


}

add_action( 'init', 'create_hr_post_type' );
```

However, only one post type is being registered on checking my admin left bar. I only see the the HR post type! What is going on in here? What i'm i missing?

I have tried reordering the code so that the IT type comes first but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 5):

An important notice from the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Post_Types#Naming_Best_Practices):

> Do pay close attention to not having your custom post type identifier
>   exceed 20 characters though, as the post_type column in the database
>   is currently a VARCHAR field of that length.

Please check out:

```
echo strlen( 'informationtechnology' );
```

If you have `WP_DEBUG` activated, then you will see this warning:

> `register_post_type` was called incorrectly. Post type names must be
>   between 1 and 20 characters in length. Please see Debugging in
>   WordPress for more information. (This message was added in version
>   4.2.)

so this is a good reminder to use it when developing your site ;-)

This part of `register_post_type()` is responsible for this check, I missed it when I first skimmed through the function but confirmed it when I ran the example by @JoeyNg'ethe:

```
if ( empty( $post_type ) || strlen( $post_type ) > 20 ) {
    _doing_it_wrong(
        __FUNCTION__, 
        __( 'Post type names must be between 1 and 20 characters in length.' ), 
       '4.2' 
    );
    return new WP_Error( 
        'post_type_length_invalid',
        __( 'Post type names must be between 1 and 20 characters in length.' ) 
    );
}
```

### EDIT

Look at the `$post_type` parameter when registering your post type

> `$post_type`
>
> (string) (required) Post type. (**max. 20 characters, cannot contain
>   capital letters or spaces**)
>
> Default: None

Comment: Was just about to post the same, the name is to long by one character

Comment: I have added the info from what I was going to post to your answer for info purposes ;-)

Comment: i knew it was something really simple. i overlooked the  string length cheers @birgire

Comment: I wonder why it doesn't throw an error to notify the user - oh it actually does, I just checked ;-) @PieterGoosen

Comment: I actually also saw it now, there was an error message added in v4.2 so if you have debugging enabled you should be able to debug this is a jiffy :-)

Comment: yeah good to know this is already available ;-) I just updated the answer with the corresponding notice @PieterGoosen

Comment: Great, that should help others :-)

Comment: glad to hear it's solved - code reviews (second pair of eyes)  are a great way to spot stuff like this   @JoeyNg'ethe

Comment: Old question but you've just saved my sanity! My parameter was 21 chars.

Comment: glad to hear it helped ;-) @JamesWalker